# Same router, same IP range, Wifi vs Ethernet not communicating well

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an internet router which supports both wired and wireless connections.

In this router I have plugged an 8-port switch in one LAN port. This switch distributes connection to 3 cabled PCs. Also on the router, there are devices connected to it over Wifi. All the IPs, both on wired devices and on wireless devices, range within 192.168.25.X (the router itself is 192.168.25.1)

When I use a simple server on a device, like php -S (serve command) it is available only to devices that are using the same type of connection (wired available for wired - wireless for wireless) even though the IP range is the same, I cannot access from a wireless device to a wired device and vice-versa.

Can you guys help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please add your netmasks, both wired and wireless, to the question; they could be on different subnets.

Comment: they are exactly in the same subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Then investigate Linef4ult's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your router has "Wireless Isolation" or a setting of a similar title enabled, disable that and clients will be able to communicate. It may require rebooting the router after changing the setting for it to take effect.

Comment: actually, I don't know.. It's a simple router from the internet provider, doesn't give me many configuration options :/